# Azure - App Insights for App Service - can it run in background?

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-appservice

While profiling our API App Service in Azure Portal, we found out that App Insights may be slowing down the API requests. It is documented in the screenshot. There is this line:

```
DiagnosticsEventListener.OnEventWritten
```

which comes from `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` and takes over a second.

Would there be a way to shorten the "Waiting" period? Or is there an option to run AppInsights in a background thread?

[image]

Comment: We've never regarded App Insights as something we run all the time; we turn it on to help diagnose specific problems